# Submit webform via custom button

Tags: javascript, webforms, 9

I want to update a webform submission via custom button.

On the same page as my webform I created a custom button in a block.

```
 <button id="myButton" onClick="submitWebform()" type="submit"> Click here!  </button>
```

with JS code

```
 function submitWebform() {
       document.getElementbyId("webform-submission-id").submit();
 }
```

But when I click on the button the page reloads but my webform is not sent.

What to do ?

My goal is to update fields with query parameters by clicking the button.

Comment: I think this function never gets triggered. Just the button behavior kicking in. Where exactly you placed the JS? Where exactly you placed the button?

Comment: I placed the JS with the Asset Injector module. The button is in the left sidebar and my webform is in the main content.

I think the function is called because when I do:  
function submitWebform() {
  document.getElementById("edit-actions-submit").click();
}

The webform is submit.

Comment: Try to change the button type to `type="button"` which would perhaps stop it acting as a submitter of its own form. Either that or receive `event` parameter in the js function like `submitWebform(event)` and call `event.preventDefault();`